# Can't seem to block Youtube using Qustodio

Tags: proxy, youtube, parental-controls

Win10: I've been limiting my kid's computer time using Qustodio mostly successfully for the past several months.  However, I can't seem to block youtube.  Neither an explicit youtube rule, or time limits, or category method seems to stop chrome or edge from loading youtube.com and its videos.  All other websites, both open and https are handled/blocked by Qustodio just like they should.  Qustodio CS has fallen back to the 'turn off your firewall and virus checkers' canard and that hasn't fixed it.

In my research to solve this, I've watched my net traffic in Fiddler, learned about proxying, and even disabled QUIC mode in Chrome.  The only dent I've made is that when fiddler's proxy/sniffer is running, some other https sites on my ban list (eg origin.com) can be reached, while they are properly blocked when fiddler is off.  In both situations Youtube still gets through.  So I'd like to dive deeper into the socket/proxy states to find where Qustodio does its magic and maybe find out how youtube is getting around that.

Can anyone tell me how to find Qustodio's interception point, or what tools might help me see how urls are intercepted by Qustodio?

UPDATE
I found a temporary solution for now. I made Windows 'prefer IPv4 addresses' by running the script MS provides here (it makes changes to your registry I think): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2533454

For some reason, Qustodio will not filter IPv6 addressed traffic on my machines, which is what the google sites were using by default. I've informed Qustodio CS of this issue.

Clark

Answer (score 1):

Qustodio doesn't control YouTube.

YouTube addresses parental controls by having an "adult" log on to enable restrictions with an option of locking down said browser.

Once locked, the YouTube will not show "restricted" content in that particular browser. You must lock Restricted Mode if you wish the limitations to stick for anyone using said browser. Meaning three browsers? Three restriction processes.

Others can log in and out of YouTube with their unique Google account, and be limited by the original restricting account.

Lifting the restriction simply requires the the original restricting account holder's Google credentials to reverse the process.

- Steps to YouTube Restricted Mode

  1. Sign on YouTube account with "parental" account. 
     Scroll to the bottom of any YouTube page. Click the drop-down menu in the "Restricted Mode" section.
  2. Click "Lock Restricted Mode on this browser." Enter in same user's password again to lock Restricted Mode on this browser.

Comment: 'Qustodio doesn't control YouTube.'
This is true, but it is supposed to block one from reaching Youtube.
My current workaround is noted below; I turn off IPv6 addressing.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Qustodio (haven't worked with it). But since you're using windows, you can edit the hosts file and manually block youtube. Here's the link: http://www.pcworld.com/article/249077/how_to_block_websites.html

Try it out and see

Comment: I'll keep that in mind as Plan B but I'd rather fix Qustodio since it's more flexible. Thanks!

Comment: That was just a fix for youtube as you stated that you can handle most of the other sites :)

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution for now.  I made Windows 'prefer IPv4 addresses' by running the script MS provides here (it makes changes to your registry I think):
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2533454

For some reason, Qustodio will not filter IPv6 addressed traffic on my machines, which is what the google sites were using by default.  I've informed Qustodio CS of this issue.

Clark

Comment: Providing the relevant information in the answer itself is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and finally tried deleting the YouTube entry in Qustodio and then added it back and that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

First, any kid that wants to get around our blocks will do so, but no reason to make it easy for them. That said, I use Qustodio with many of my clients. To handle Youtube, I have them log in with their parental accounts. Then go into the restricted mode for Youtube (at bottom of the first page) and set it up. Then log out of Youtube at the top where they log in. Then return to the bottom of the page and hit the X to conceal those settings.

For Google Search (both image and regular search), I have the parent log in at the top right corner. Then in the google search window at the bottom right, enter Settings. In the page that appears, enable SafeSearch Filtering and click the Lock option. Then log out of the parent's account.

Now both are locked down, and they require the parent's login to remove the locks/restrictions.

This is great because kids and other users can actually log into that same web browser with their credentials and do their thing while not upsetting the parental controls established by Mom and Dad.

Comment: This appears just to be spam for the website since it does not actually answer the author's question.  I am calling a duck a duck from my point of view.  The signature portion has no business being in an answer, we don't do signatures, on the off chance I am being to critical.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, thanks for your answer. I removed your signature so that people who are tickle o' the "flag as spam" button won't demolish your post.

Comment: I have no connection with Qustodio. I also provided the answer.